"Too long maps chain. May cause performance overhead"
Idea flags code usage that has more than 2 maps:
 single
   .map(...)
   .map(...)
   .map(...)


There is no other explanation for it and I couldn't find any documentation except for this https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-218263/Warn-long-map-call-sequence
Is there really a significant performance overhead?
I think it's unlikely I should worry about creating a few extra objects.
It seems even less likely given that rx-java has operator merging. Would it be a concern without operator merging (e.g. Mutiny)?
Also why is this a problem for reactive, but not for map() methods on Optional or Java Streams? (At least Idea doesn't warn about those)

RxJava doesn't merge map()s because supposedly the JIT is good enough to aggressively inline callbacks, at least on desktop. There is an overhead per map which can be troubling if your callbacks do relatively trivial work compared to invoking the next callback in the chain.

If JIT is good enough to inline them then where does the overhead come from?

There is still the memory overhead of the infrastructure and per operator fields. It's not a lot though. I'd say IntelliJ is a bit skittish when it comes to Stream/Rx. Probably nothing to worry about in general.

This is my thinking -- the overhead is insignificant in a typical setup of a web server querying a DB. The web and DB frameworks are going to create a lot of short lived objects anyway. Also the overhead is constant and not increasing with the size of the data processed
